# How to transfer data from one form to other (after a lookup to the original page where the request was made) Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, perl

Here is a situation, I have a page which has three text fields, and with default values, and a hyperlink to do a lookup of the database, and return parameters  back to the page where the hyperlink was accessed and the text box must be filled with the looked up data ?

Comment: Could you post your code as well ?

Comment: There is no code yet, for now its a thing that I need to do

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow isn't the right place for your question.

Answer (score 0):

We did it using `window.opener.document`.In JavaScript, the parent window elements can be accessed from the child window.

Once, the value in the popup is selected, it can be set as follows

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("data").value = <selected value from popup>
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint , 'm trying to do this via a hyperlink, which leaves the page and once the value get searched and selected from a list, it needs to leave that page and fill the data in the original page where the link was accessed, this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. U can open a popup using myWindow = window.open("<url>", "myWindow", "width=100, height=100"); When the value is selected from the list, u can write a function which will set the values in the original page using window.opener.document. Once the values are set, you can use myWindow.close(); to close the popup.